# boost::spirit::qi - optional match

Tags: boost-spirit, option-type

I'm new to boost::spirit. I've stumbled over a simple thing. Given a string like this:

```
Optional text KEYWORD further text
```

I need to parse it into a string like this:

```
T KEYWORD further text
```

where 'T' appears only if optional text exists. What I've come to was this rule:

```
start = (+(char_ - "KEYWORD"))  [_val += 'T']  |  eps
        >> "KEYWORD"            [_val += _1]   
        >> *char_               [_val += _1];
```

But it fails. Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: Thanks, sehe. Spirit seems to me a bit tricky.

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean. It's worth the effort for me, but in case you are looking for something simpler to get right (and faster to compile) I heartily recommend [`CoCo/R C++`](http://ssw.jku.at/coco/#CPP) which I used before Spirit for 'all' my parsing needs. It has the distinct benefit of being able to reuse existing grammars in a large variety of languages (C#, Java, C++, C#, VB, Oberon, Ruby, Python, Oberon, Ada etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It heavily depends on the target types you are assigning the attributes to, and (to a lesser extent) what the whitespace policy is, i.e. whether your grammar uses a skipper or not.

For now, here's what I'd write:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename V>
   void test(const V& input)
{
    typedef typename V::const_iterator It;

    using namespace qi;
    rule<It, bool(), space_type>        preambule = +(!lit("KEYWORD") > omit[char_]) > attr(true) | attr(false);
    rule<It, std::string(), space_type> word      = +char_;

    It first(input.begin()), last(input.end());

    bool hasPreamble;
    std::string furtherText;

    bool ok = phrase_parse(first, last,
            preambule > "KEYWORD" > raw[ *char_ ], space,
            hasPreamble, furtherText);

    if (ok)
        std::cout << (hasPreamble?"T ":"") << "KEYWORD " << furtherText << std::endl;

    if (first!=last)
        std::cout << "hmmm: '" << std::string(first, last) << "'" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    test(std::string("KEYWORD further text"));
    test(std::string("one KEYWORD further text"));
    test(std::string("one two KEYWORD further text"));
}
```

Ouput:

```
KEYWORD further text
T KEYWORD further text
T KEYWORD further text
```